# Serious problem with the speed of full screen textField animation

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

I can't find any proper way to make a long textField move fluently horizontally across the screen in full screen mode. I tried many ways but it always gets stuck from time to time for a few milliseconds and ruins the whole experience. Please, if someone can help me to find a way to best animate a large dynamic string on full screen, I would be very grateful.
I tried using var myTween:Tween = new Tween(myText, "x", None.easeNone, 0, newX, 80, true); even moving the x manually using a timer or on frame event; it always gets stuck for a few milliseconds pretty often when the text moves across the screen in full screen.
I also tried using Bitmap but it gets a bit too pixelated and no noticeable improvement in performance. 
Maybe someone knows a way to optimize the animation somehow in ActionScript 3 or use some other controler than a textField.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite late, but here's a list of a few things you could try:

- You could try using a tweening engine like [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/), which does animation frame-independently, so it will help to make the motion appear more smooth.
- If the text isn't changing while it moves, you could set the TextField's cacheAsBitmap property to 'true'.
- Make sure the AntiAlias mode is "Animation" rather than "Readability" as Readability mode will look strange on a moving TextField and it will slow things down as Flash will try to rerender it constantly.
- Manually draw the entire TextField to a bitmap, and move the bitmap. It sounds like you may have already tried this, but if done correctly it should vastly increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your machine can't keep up with all the processes running at the same time. This is a reality on almost all collaborative applications.

To diminish the effect, try reducing your animations framerate. It will be less fluid but the frame duration will be constant and the skip much less noticeable. It might be a necessary compromise with your current problem.